# SSISDB - Certificates expired

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssis, ssis-2014

I was doing an audit of certificates in our environments to find those that have either expired or are expiring in 30 days. I used the following query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    sys.certificates
WHERE   expiry_date < DATEADD(DAY,30,GETDATE());
```

I noticed in SSISDB that there are a large number of expired certificates:

[image]

What are these certificates used for, is it an issue that they have expired? I have not heard any complaints from our development team that SSIS isn't working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All certificates have an expiry_date, but for most uses of certificates in SQL Server, the expiry is not checked.  A certificate that protects a symmetric key used for [data encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/encrypt-a-column-of-data?view=sql-server-ver15) in a database (which is what I think these are), can be used indefinitely.  IE SQL Server doesn't check the expiry_date when you run [OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/open-symmetric-key-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

From the docs:

> EXPIRY_DATE = 'datetime'
>
> Is the date on which the certificate expires.
> If not specified, EXPIRY_DATE is set to a date one year after
> START_DATE. EXPIRY_DATE is in UTC time and can be specified in any
> format that can be converted to a date and time. SQL Server Service
> Broker checks the expiration date. Backup with Encryption using
> certificates also checks the expiration date and will not allow a new
> backup to be created with an expired certificate, but will allow
> restores with an expired certificate. However, expiration is not
> enforced when the certificate is used for database encryption or
> Always Encrypted.

[CREATE CERTIFICATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-certificate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)